# Association in PHP

Tags: php

I'm pretty new in PHP, I started to learn OOP, and I'm trying to learn association, however, my code isn't working, I really don't know why, but the problem is on the line 38, when I call the method Driving, it says that must be one instance of Person, what it means?

**Src:**

```
<?php

class Person
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Car
{

    private $size;
    private $model;

    public function __construct($size, $model)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function Driving(Person $person)
    {
        echo "The size is: {$this->size}<br>";
        echo "Look at the model of the car: " . $this->model;
        echo "Look at the name of the person: " . $person->getName();
    }
}
$obj1 = new Person("Someone");
$obj2 = new Car("120", "Nothing");
$obj2->Driving($person);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
$obj1 = new Person("Someone");
$obj2 = new Car("120", "Nothing");
$obj2->Driving($person);
```

You used `$person` but the person object is `$obj2`.

Use `$obj2` instead of `$person` or rename `$obj2` to `$person`.

Comment: Not sure a silly typo really deserves an answer :)

Comment: I tried but no succcess

Comment: @brunasilvinha same error or what happens?

Comment: Oh, I realized now, the problem was in the variable $obj1, I should call it by $person, and then use it in the method Driving()

Comment: Thank you so much, you gave me the idea to solve it

Comment: Yes. You can either do this or call `$obj2->Driving($obj1)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's good, thanks